# Convert players position to screen not world?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

how do I convert my players x.position to position on screen and not in world?

I have a player node as I walk forwards, if I print(player.position.x) its often something like 2000

But when I walk backwards I want to stop at the edge of screen and not go back until player.position.x = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I figured it out,

```
let playerLocation:CGPoint = self.convertPoint(player.position, fromNode: world)
```

thanks.